# How to ETL using stream processing

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, etl, apache-flink, business-intelligence

I have a SQL server database, Where millions of rows are (inserted/deleted/updated) every day. I'm supposed to propose an ETL solution to transfer data from this database to a data warehouse. At first i tried to work with CDC and SSIS, but the company i work in want a more real time solution. I've done some research and discovered stream processing. I've also looked for Spark and Flink tutorials but i didn't find anything.

my question is which stream processing tool do i choose? and how do i learn to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

**Open Source Solution**
You can use Confluent Kafka Integration tool to track Insert and Update operation using Load Timestamp. These would automatically provide you the real time data which get inserted or Updated in the database. If you are having a soft delete in your database , that can be also tracked by using load timestamp and active or inactive flag. 
If there is no such flags then you need to provide some logic on which partition might get updated on that day and send that entire partition into the stream which is definitely resource exhaustive.

**Paid Solution**
There is a paid tool called ***Striim CDC*** which can provide real time responses to your system